# Cumulative Layout Shift is becoming a ranking factor - (Thought and what it means?)

Tags: google, changes

Has anyone heard of the Cumulative Layout Shift becoming a ranking factor?

I need to prepare for it, but really trying to work out what it all means from a design point of view, it seems it is aimed at a number of things, one being the movement of elements from its original placement?

Does anyone have any advice or thoughts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds more like an SEO issue that a UX question